# How to export Epubs from iPad to my Mac?

Tags: itunes, ipad, mac, books

I have a bunch of books in iBooks in the ePub format from different sources. Some are iTunes, some Humble, LeanPub etc. I have notes and markings in there as well.

I would like to export all of that to my Mac. The iTunes books are ok. But I cannot find a way to export the other books and notes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied this section from: http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-export-ibooks-from-iphone-ipad-to-computer/ I am not sure how much of it is useful to you.

1). Get a file explorer. Usually, iExplorer should do just fine.
2). Connect your iPhone or iPad to the computer and fire up iExplorer
3). Open your iPhone/iPad as a mounted device and navigate to:
Media → Books → Purchases

The funniest thing is that you won’t be able to decipher what file corresponds to what book from your library because, like music, the file names are encrypted. Nevertheless, you can copy stuff now.
This folder method gives you access to all files including .epub, .pdf and all types you have purchased. You might want to check out epub to pdf converters to make a readable copy of the epub iBooks you’ve got.

Comment: Thanks, I tried iExplorer, but it just crashes when used with Yosemite...

Comment: Then use another file explorer, google is full of ideas, like http://www.i-funbox.com/